# Detect mouse clicks on QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

How can I detect mouse clicks in QWebEngineView widget?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.view.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
             print ("Widget click")
        return super(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: What is `view`? Besides that, why are you using `super()` with the QMainWindow argument in the event filter?

Comment: view is a widget type "QWebEngineView". I don't know why i using super(), i just copy it. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What i need return?

Comment: The problem is not what you're returning, but the argument of super, which should be the current class: `super(MyWin, self)`, or, in case of python 3, just `super()` without any argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the view is the QWebEngineView object and you want to track its mouse event then you should use the focusProxy which is an internal widget that handles these types of events. On the other hand you must correctly apply inheritance.

```py
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.view.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.ui.view.focusProxy() and event.type() == event.MouseButtonPress:
            print("Widget click")
        return super(MyWin, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: I got this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'installEventFilter'

Comment: @Cliffhanger mmm, try add `self.show()` and  `self.ui.view.show()` before `self.ui.view.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self)`. If it doesn't work then you need to provide the code for the Ui_MainWindow class to analyze the cause of the error

Comment: Thanks for help. I found the error in UI_MainWindow class, i don't load page in self.view. I added this line: self.view.load(url) after i created QWebEngineWiev in UI_MainWindow class and now it work. Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: I also got error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'installEventFilter'. so is there any other workaround here except using focusProxy()?

Comment: @iMath try add self.show() and self.ui.view.show() before self.ui.view.focusProxy().installEventFilter(self)

Comment: Thanks ! I found a workaround, but still have minor issues , any solutions ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696183/pyqt5-mouseclick-and-source-code-in-qwebengineview#comment117914212_40697097

Comment: in PyQt6: `event.type() == event.Type.MouseButtonPress`